# String.split ignore content inside square brackets with regex

Tags: python, regex, split

I have a chatlog that is as follows:

```
12-09-18 00:31:40   @966 [playerwithoutspaces] to TEAM: Hello all
12-09-18 00:32:11   @966 [playerswith[inname] to ALL:   Helloall
12-09-18 00:30:15   @966 [player name with spaces] to ALL:  Hello all]
```

I'm trying to get date, time, id,name, to, chat and content with `re.split("""[\s\t](?![^[]*\])""", line, 6)`
But it doesn't quite work. The problem is, if the `content` contains [ or ], it doesn't split the line properly.

So the result is:

`['12-09-18', '00:30:15', '@966', '[player name with spaces] to ALL:\tHello all]', '']`

When it should be:

`['12-09-18', '00:30:15', '@966', '[player name with spaces]', 'to', 'ALL:', '\tHello all]']`

I tried fiddling around with matching ] just certain amount of times, but that didn't work.

I forgot to mention that content is either preceded by a tab \t or whitespace \s, so it varies.

Here is the code as requested:

```
file = open("chatlog.txt", encoding="ANSI")
...
async def main():
    for line in file.readlines():
        await handle_chatlog_line(line)

async def handle_chatlog_line(line):
    print(re.split("""[\s\t](?![^[]*\])""", line, 6))
    date, time, ingame_client_id, client_name, irrelevant, chat, content = re.split("""[\s\t](?![^[]*\])""", line, 6)
```

And it crashes on the 3rd line in chatlog due to the regex being incorrect and therefore split not producing enough items.

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/0Lr4iw (see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JL0SKC/1)), please let know if this approach works for you.

Comment: I solved this by using re.match instead of re.split, which is more suitable for something like this. Answer below soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that splitting insn't the way to go in a situation like this, so I ended up using re.match:

```
match = re.match("(\d\d-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d)\s+(@\d+) \[(.+)\] to (TEAM|ALL):\s+(.+)",line)
```